# What is the correct reaction of sulfur dioxide with chlorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm confused in reaction of $\ce{SO2}$ with $\ce{Cl2}$. Some source states the given reaction (1), while others state the reaction (2):

$$\begin{align}
\ce{SO2 + Cl2 &-> SOCl2 + Cl2O \tag{1}}\\
\ce{SO2 + Cl2 &-> SO2Cl2 \tag{2}}
\end{align}$$

While I read in NCERT Chemistry 12 part-II page-198 that chlorine oxidises $\ce{SO2}$ to $\ce{SO3}$. I wish to know the specific condition in which the particular reactions will occur.

Comment: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=23152

Comment: Which sources quote reaction 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Sulfuryl chloride ($\ce{SO2Cl2}$) is prepared by the reaction of $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ over activated charcoal, details of the preparation are here [1](http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-sulfuryl-chloride/).

Thionyl chloride may be prepared from $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ but the reaction requires an equivalent of $\ce{SCl2}$ to be present.

Comment: Can you also add the equations of the two reactions?